# MVC4 Session not persisted between requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4

**BIG update after some good testing**

I have a MVC4 web application and I'm simply debugging it in visual studio 2010 just to learn some more about webdevelopment (and MVC in particular). I'm playing with Session now. But I don't understand why I lose my variables after a new httprequest.

It's like this question: [Losing my session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331793/losing-my-session-variables)

My web.config for the session part looks like:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"
   cookieless="false"
   timeout="20"/>
```

My little test project to isolate the problem works fine and looks like:

Controllers
- HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Test/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string t = (string)Session["Test1"];
        ViewBag.Result = t;
        return View();
    }

}
```

- MysessionController

  public class MysessionController : Controller
      {
          //
          // GET: /Mysession/

  ```
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View(new Models.Mysession() {ID = Session.SessionID});
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Index(Models.Mysession mySession) {
          Session["Test1"] = "Bla";
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }

  }
  ```

Models

```
public class Mysession {
    [Required]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Views

- Home

  - Index.cshtml

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    ### Index

    @*@ViewBag.Result*@
    @((string)Session["Test1"])
    @Html.ActionLink("My session", "Index", "Mysession")
- Mysession

  - Index.cshtml

    @model SessionTest.Models.Mysession
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

  ### Index

  @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

  ```
  @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Mysession</legend>
       <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
      </div>
      <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
      </p>
  </fieldset>
  ```

  }

This looks in a nutshell like my main application, the DIFFERENCE is: In MysessionController in the HTTPPOST Index action where the session variable is set I acces a XML file to look up something.

The XML file is my persistent storage because I don't have a SQL server. My question is, can this affect my session?

If so, I would like to point out that I acces the XML file PRIOR to setting the variable in the session. So it seems strange to me. But I've pinpointed by testing that if I don't acces the XML file then the vars in the session are fine. If I acces the XML file the vars in the session are null after the RedirectToAction.

I don't know why I didn't came to this conclusion yesterday. Sorry everybody. I did some sloppy testing yesterday.

Comment: What exactly do you do to redo steps 3 to 5?

Comment: @Grumbler85 Thank you for replying. Sorry I wasn't clear in the 1st place. I editted my question. Is this more clear?

Comment: No - what do you do with your browser? Is it the same instance? Is it a new tab from the browser, which is opened by VS?
Did you follow the code with the debugger?

Comment: See update in main post.

Comment: @TLRonin you didn't write anything about browser

Comment: Do u have any Controller with `SessionLess Attribute` ?

Comment: Did you check what cookies are submitted to the user?
Fiddler will tell you - perhaps there's a Problem that you restart the session or something like that.

Comment: @Garath Yes I did, see "Update" please at bottom of post. Or do you mean, what kind of browser? I test in the latest Firefox and IE9.

Comment: @PKKG Checked that and everything is on default (since I haven't explicitly set an attribute).

Comment: @Grumbler85 Yeah, what makes a session restart? That is what I want to know.

Comment: Perhaps it's time for more code: Constructor, ActionMethods, Events

Comment: @Grumbler85 I'm so sorry. I don't know what I've done yesterday. But today my tests are much more logical and make more sense to me. I've updated the question accordingly. Could you review my question again please if it's not too much trouble? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, I would like to thank everybody that has put time in this question. After I got myself together and finally conducted a proper test I pinpointed the problem to accessing a XML file on the hard drive. Don't know what I was messing about yesterday...

I found trough Google several posts and articles about losing your session after accessing files. Like this one:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx

Fantastic case study by Tessa Ferrandez. And to lesser extend: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/998370.aspx/1

And:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2005/12/01/499144.aspx

**Conclusion**

When you access files in any way of your website the AppDomain will be refreshed and this will refresh your session.

Never put a file you need to access through your website in your 'bin' folder. I've moved my XML file to App_Data and the variables are persisted in the Session.

Summed up my answer on my blog: http://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/losing-session-variables-with-asp-net/

Comment: Well yes - putting Data into the bin folder is a bad idea.. nice you made it - and nice, that you wrote down the conclusions here! +1 for posting the answer yourself