# Make Session last longer

Tags: asp.net, session

In my web.config I have this:

```
<sessionState timeout="70"/>
```

However, after 5 minutes my session is null and my program crashes. How to make this time longer?

Here is how I initialize it:

```
Session["mySession"] = "blah blah";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the applicationpool timeout http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Using forms authetication? It got it's own timeout/

Comment: Does it happen on your dev environment our on production, your sure you are not "building" your application in between and not changing the web.config

Comment: Also check out this question for a couple of solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515947/losing-session-state

Comment: I'm not changing the web. config. I run my app, login, everything is fine, I wait 5 minutes and crash.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the timeout like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 200000
```

Answer (score 0):

the time that you putting inside the Web.Config

`<sessionState timeout="60"/>` (it in minutes)

affect on the

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 60
```

**or**

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 60
```