# Is there anyway to skip app domain recycle during App_Code changes?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, session-variables

I am working on a change request to one of our ASP.NET projects, where most of the code change/update required on App_Code folder. But for each change for App_Code files leads to app domain recycles and then repeated logins. I want to avoid this for development environment.

what i tried:

- Increased sessionState timeout.
- Increased Idle Time-out for Apppool in IIS[7.5].
- I didn't change sessionState mode from "InPorc" as it causing some errors[I think we need to declare some classes as serializable with StateServer and SQLServer. I don't want to make changes other parts of the project where i am not working].

I went through below posts, got idea that App_Code changes will cause app domain recycle but i am looking for solution to avoid it[if possible].

[Losing Session State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515947/losing-session-state)

[What causes an application pool in IIS to recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx

Update:

Application running on IIS7.5 and Windows 7 Professional with Service Pack 1

Comment: Have you tried setting the `disallowRotationOnConfigChange` to true? This can be found within an Application Pool's Advanced Settings under the Recycling subheading as the "Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes" attribute.

Comment: @Brian Gilreath, I tried it now, its not working.

Comment: @Brain Gilreath, Thanks for your response. I think the fix you provided is applies to Windows server 2012 and Windows 8.1 only but my application running on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't skip recycling an app domain without changing the sessionState mode to other than "InProc"

https://forums.iis.net/p/1226481/2103541.aspx?Is+there+anyway+to+skip+app+domain+recycle+during+App_Code+changes+

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a MS hotfix for this problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052480