# sessionState only works on localhost

Tags: asp.net

Im currently developing an ASP.NET webpage that uses sessionState to keep a limited time of inactivity before it logs out by itself (the users are stored in a database in SQL Server).
The problem is that it works like a charm on the localhost, but when I upload the page to the remote server it doesn't lasts more than 10 minutes or so (I need at least 30 minutes). It looks something like this on the web.config file

```
    <sessionState timeout="30">
</sessionState>
```

A friend of mine told me that I should be looking at the IIS to fix my problem, I already did that but I don't know where it could be.

I don't have much experience in this language so please don't be mad if my question is dumb.

Comment: Check this post out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515947/losing-session-state

Comment: Check the Idle Timeout of your App Pool in IIS