# Windows authentication IIS session timeout (popup)

Tags: asp.net, windows, session, authentication, iis

We have hosted MVC web application IIS 8.5 in Dev and Prod Environments. In Dev it rarely asks for the windows authentication popup (where users fill their credentials to authenticate). But in Prod it asks this very frequently. I am sure that the IIS are using the same settings, web.config are also the same settings(except DB connections). Tried tweaking the timeout in IIS and web.config but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to this thread for some common reasons for the problem, hopefully something helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515947/losing-session-state

Comment: I have ensured that the recycling settings are the same, the default is still 20 minutes in both of them. I rechecked the things mentioned in your suggestion mentioned under ( If you are using IIS 7 or 7.5, here are a few things to look for) but it is all the same.

Comment: Prompt in browsers can be caused by any 401 response from the server, not merely 401.1. So at this stage, don't guess and collect more information.